# Safari uses millions of gigabyte of ram

Tags: javascript, safari

I'm curious to what may cause Safari report millions or billions of GB of memory usage on a web application. This is a timeline report for Safari on iPhone 13 Pro.

Does anybody know what may cause this issue?

[Safari memory usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Law8S.png)

Comment: petabytes? on an iphone? exabytes? I believe you may be exaggerating the numbers a bit

Comment: @Bravo Check the screenshot. OP is clearly wondering why Safari reports completely absurd numbers.

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me. What else could it be?

Comment: A bug in Safari!!? Never considered that the new Internet Explorer would have a bug :p

Comment: at current chip sizes, the storage for 18 zettabytes would not comfortably fit in your pocket ... probably wouldn't fit in your house :p

Comment: Well, it's obviously a bug, but I wonder what may cause it. Because the webapp I'm trying to run crashes and reloads on a iPhone 12 with 4GB of RAM, but not on a iPhone 13 Pro with 6GB of RAM. I'm just trying to find answers to what may cause this issue, and possibly why the app crashes reloaded (I'm suspecting it has to do with memory usage).